# Where can I find sales figures on pharmaceutical drugs listed by manufacturer?

Tags: data-request, openfda

I have some set of data from openFDA that looks like:

```
Nausea reports concomitant w/ Fluoxetine, by manufacturer.
+--------------+-------------------+
| Manufacturer | Number of reports |
+--------------+-------------------+
| Dista        | 1344              |
+--------------+-------------------+
| Mylan        | 1306              |
+--------------+-------------------+
| Teva         | 1129              |
+--------------+-------------------+
| Aurobindo    | 1064              |
+--------------+-------------------+
```

I need to control this data for the popularity of each manufacturer; if Dista sells 98% of all fluoxetine consumed, the other manufacturers may have a nausea problem (or perhaps they just report reactions much more than Dista).

Where can I find sales numbers for drug manufacturers? Is that data available, and if not, what else can I do to control for this?

Comment: Unfortunately, the short answer is that there is no one place to get this data in a full and accurate way. You can use open data sets such as the Medicare Part D drug data (searchable at http://projects.propublica.org/checkup/) but for a more comprehensive via you'll likely need to license the data from someone like http://surescripts.com/. If you find a better way, please do let me know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is not open data** but from my experience looking for data like this for quite a while even on a site with a lot of terms and conditions, the following is a relatively robust source:

http://www.drugs.com/stats/top100/units has sales and unit figures for the top 100 drugs of each quarter going back to 2011 and then top 200 from 2003 through 2010. The source is listed as `IMS Health (Midas)`.

Here are three Quora answers that were somewhat helpful to me while researching IMS' offerings a little bit further:

1. https://www.quora.com/IMS-Health/How-much-does-IMS-data-cost
2. https://www.quora.com/IMS-Health/How-is-a-contract-with-IMS-Health-structured-How-does-it-charge-pharma-companies-100M+-each-year
3. https://www.quora.com/IMS-Health/How-does-IMS-Health-get-their-prescrption-data

---

In terms of actual open data, the best I can find is usage by prescription drug class from the CDC: http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/hus/contents2012.htm#092 . It is table 92 ('Selected prescription drug classes used in the past 30 days, by sex and age: United States, selected years 1988-1994 through 2007-2010') of *Health, United States*, "an annual report on trends in health statistics"